# Почему в слайдере картинки нулевого размера и не подгружается навигация?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, изображения

Есть сайт на wordpress в котором есть записи принадлежащие определенной (рубрике) категории, для которой я создал шаблон отображения на основе шаблона страницы блога, в котом формат записи галерея отображается в виде слайдера:

код формата галереи `gallery-slider.php`:

```
<div class="flexslider postslider" style="max-height:365px; padding-bottom:0; overflow:hidden">
        <ul class="slides">
      <?php    
        $args = array(
                    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                     'category'        => 'photo',
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
                    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                    'post_status' => null,
                    'posts_per_page' => -1
        );          
        $attachments = get_posts( $args );
         if ( $attachments ) {
          foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
             echo '<li>';
             echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'format-standard');
             echo '</li>';
            }
         }
             ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Но на выходе я получаю слайдер с изображениями нулевого размера:

```
<div class="flexslider postslider" style="max-height:365px; padding-bottom:0; overflow:hidden">
        <ul class="slides">
      <li><img width="704" height="400" src="../wp-content/uploads/2016/03/C4o-y2ary0-704x400.jpg" class="attachment-format-standard size-format-standard" alt="_C4o-y2ary0"></li>
    ...      
        </ul>
    </div>
```

хотя должен быть вот такой вывод:

```
<div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 400px;">
    <ul class="slides" style="width: 8200%; margin-left: -2241px;">
        <li class="clone" style="width: 747px; float: left; display: block;">
            <img width="704" height="400" src="../wp-content/uploads/2016/03/zs380lziUc-704x400.jpg" class="attachment-format-standard size-format-standard" alt="-zs380lziUc">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging"></ol>
<ul class="flex-direction-nav">
    <li>
        <a class="flex-prev" href="#">Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="flex-next" href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

не создается оболочка `flex-viewport` и элементы навигации и  при наведении на изображение в редакторе кода пишет: `0 x 0 narural 704pixels x 400pixels` и по ссылке на изображение переходит, все в порядке - что это может означать?

Comment: а где в вашем php flex-viewport?

Comment: @Jean-Claude  нету, но этот код 1 в 1 с шаблоном блога. насколько я понимаю в этом слайдере `flex-viewport` из скриптов подтягивается

Comment: не подтягивается

Comment: @Jean-Claude у меня догадка, что просто, что `flex-slider` подключается к определенным видам страниц - вот ее и проверю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем, нашел правильный ответ. Мало того, что в теме слайдер был подключен для определенных страниц:

```
if ( is_home() || is_front_page()|| is_page_template('template-blog.php')) { 
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.flexslider-min', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js','','', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.flexslider.start.main', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.flexslider.start.main.js','','', true);
    }
```

так еще и путь был прописан через `get_template_directory_uri()`, а у меня все подключается через дочернюю тему, т.е. `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.
Исправил - заработало!